# How can we store a username-password combination in keychain in encrypted format

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain, offlineapps

I need to implement offline login in my application.Currently I am storing passwords in keychain which have been used to login at least once when the app is online.But right now I am not checking the username password combination. If I have multiple users for a single device , storing only passwords won't be enough. So Can anyone of you suggest something which can be done with no security breaches.

Comment: Do yin want to remember all users or just the last one ?

Comment: @bobby: need to remember all the users

Comment: So i suggest you to store the password, using the login as a key. something like : acccount_test@test.com / password. You can encode the md5 value of the passcode to improve security too

Comment: @bobby: Thank you for your response Bobby. Let me try it.

Comment: I did add it as an answer. Can you up vote and mark it as the choosen answer ? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to store the password, using the login as a key. something like : `acccount_test@test.com / password`.

You can encode the `md5` value of the passcode to improve security too

Answer (score 0):

you can use  NSURLCredential depend on this [link](https://coderwall.com/p/kjb3lw/storing-password-in-keychain-the-smart-way)

**Store**

```
NSURLCredential *credential;

credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:username password:password persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistencePermanent];
[[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] setCredential:credential forProtectionSpace:self.loginProtectionSpace];
```

**Get Store Data**

```
NSURLCredential *credential;
NSDictionary *credentials;

credentials = [[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] credentialsForProtectionSpace:self.loginProtectionSpace];
credential = [credentials.objectEnumerator nextObject];
NSLog(@"User %@ already connected with password %@", credential.user, credential.password);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save it in the device Keychain which designed to save sensitive information. Download a wrapper from this [Ray Wenderlich tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/92667/securing-ios-data-keychain-touch-id-1password) and encrypt the password with sha512

```
#import "KeychainWrapper.h"
#include <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>

-(void)createSHA512andSaveToKeychain:(NSString*)unencryptedPasswd {
    const char *passwdBytes= [unencryptedPasswd cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *passwordData = [NSData dataWithBytes:passwdBytes length:unencryptedPasswd.length];
    uint8_t digest[CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_SHA512(passwordData.bytes, passwordData.length, digest);
    NSMutableString *encryptedPasswd= [NSMutableString  stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];
    for(int i = 0; i < CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
        [encryptedPasswd appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];
    }

    // Save the password in the device keychain
    KeychainWrapper *keychainWrapper = [[KeychainWrapper alloc] init];
    [keychainWrapper mySetObject:encryptedPasswd forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
    [keychainWrapper writeToKeychain];
}
```

To retrieve the password:

```
// Retrieve the pwd from the device keychain
KeychainWrapper *keychainWrapper = [[KeychainWrapper alloc] init];
NSString *pwd = [keychainWrapper myObjectForKey:@"v_Data"];
```

Comment: Can we match the retrieved password with the correct username? I have multiple users for the same device

Comment: Yes. If you need to store multiple passwords (and user names), you will need a different wrapper from Apple. Please see this link:http://devmonologue.com/ios/ios/storing-sensitive-information-in-the-iphones-keychain/ Basically you initialize the keychain class with a user specific initializer using the  "initWithIdentifier:" method.