# Should data placed in keychain encrypted manually?

Tags: ios, encryption, keychain

Sorry for this yes/no question.

Should we encrypt the password with a separate algorithm while saving in keychain or leave the `keychain` default `cryptography` mechanism?

**If i have to why?**

I am thinking to store username and password inside keychain which is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to Store Username or Email and Password locally then Keychain is the best option. Have a look into [KeyChain Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html).

**`All the password data in the keychain is protected using the Triple Digital Encryption Standard (3DES).`**

You can also refer one of the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312871/what-encryption-algorithm-does-the-ios-keychain-use-to-protect-data)

It is always good practice to provide one more layer of security if you have some confidential data. So its all up to you.

You can encrypt it before inserting into `Keychain`.

You can use [AES](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor) and many more encryption technique which is available in iOS.

Download KeyChain **`Apple Official Sample Code`** From [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007797)

Comment: @Costello have a look to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use additional encryption for it. Read more about iOS Security in [iOS Security Guide](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf) including Keychain working.

Comment: can you explain me abit..I have seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41018406/how-can-we-store-a-username-password-combination-in-keychain-in-encrypted-format) question on doing that?

Comment: And also [here](https://coderwall.com/p/kjb3lw/storing-password-in-keychain-the-smart-way)